# How to turn off CDP on a Cisco SD2005?

Tags: cisco

So I have this Cisco switch (Cisco SD2005) and I need to turn off the (probably) CDP:

```
14:58:53.235097 01:80:c2:00:00:01 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x8874), length 60:
    0x0000:  e008 8f4f d8c2 fa05 da4e 5010 0000 0000  ...O.....NP.....
    0x0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

How can I do this?

I'm not familiar with Cicso switches so I need a little description for it.

AFAIK this is how can I turn CDP off (got this from my friend):

```
switch# enable
switch# configure terminal
switch# no cdp run
switch# show cdp neighbors

 % CDP is not enabled           

!--- This message indicates that CDP is disabled on this device.

swithch# end
```

But this switch is an "unmanaged" switch (?)

p.s.: is the tcpdumped data CDP at all??

Comment: The frame you captured is not CDP but STP (the source mac is from a "reserved" block).

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you explain your actual problem. This is a "It's very important that I get the demons out of my grandmother's head. What should I do?" kind of question. (There's may or may not be a real problem, but whatever it is, the way you've explained it won't get you a useful answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not CDP. It is some kind of broadcom loop detection traffic. See: http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2006/0285499.html.

My guess is that it from a client connected to the switch, not from the switch itself.

Comment: No, hosts don't care about L2 loops. But it's indeed a broadcom loop detection frame.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why do you think you need to disable CDP?

Secondly, I don't think that switch even has CDP.

Finally, if it's unmanaged then you're out of luck anyway. The whole *thing* with unmanaged switches is that there is no configuration to edit. It's a plug and play device, and you get what you get.